# I have an element (inside a function) that I need to get using "document.getElementById" (which lies outside). How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am relatively new to JavaScript and React. After lots of trial and error, I realised that I need to first load the element on the page before using the document.getElementById but I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Here is my code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './node_modules/dayjs';

var dayjs = require('dayjs')
//import dayjs from 'dayjs' // ES 2015
dayjs().format()

const weekday = require("dayjs/plugin/weekday");
const weekOfYear = require("dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear");

dayjs.extend(weekday);
dayjs.extend(weekOfYear);

const App = () => {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            
            <div className="calendar-month" />
                
                <section className="calendar-month-header"/>
                <div id="selected-month" class="calendar-month-header-selected-month" />
                    <div className="calendar-month-header-selectors"/>
                        <span id="previous-month-selector" >{'<'}</span>
                        <span id="present-month-selector">{'>'}</span>
                        <span id="next-month-selector">{'<'}</span>
        
                <ul id="days-of-week"class="day-of-week" />
                <ul id="calendar-days" class="days-grid" />

            <h1>Meal planner</h1>

        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

window.onload = load = () => {
    const WEEKDAYS = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
    const INITIAL_YEAR = dayjs().format("YYYY");
    const INITIAL_MONTH = dayjs().format("M");
    const daysOfWeekElement = document.getElementById("days-of-week");

// Loop through the array of weekdays
WEEKDAYS.forEach(weekday => {
    // For each item in the array, make a list item element
    const weekDayElement = document.createElement("li");
    // Append a child element inside the list item...
    daysOfWeekElement.appendChild(weekDayElement);
    weekDayElement.innerText = weekday;
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to manually mutate the DOM. Do all that with/in React. Here is an example for `WEEKDAYS`:

```js
const WEEKDAYS = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];

const App = () => {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            
            <div className="calendar-month" />
                
                <section className="calendar-month-header"/>
                <div id="selected-month" class="calendar-month-header-selected-month" />
                    <div className="calendar-month-header-selectors"/>
                        <span id="previous-month-selector" >{'<'}</span>
                        <span id="present-month-selector">{'>'}</span>
                        <span id="next-month-selector">{'<'}</span>
        
                <ul id="days-of-week"class="day-of-week">
                  {WEEKDAYS.map(weekday => <li>{weekday}</li>)}
                </ul>
                <ul id="calendar-days" class="days-grid" />

            <h1>Meal planner</h1>

        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note how the `<li>` elements are dynamically generated from the array.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to integrate your code into mine, but when I did, it threw a "Target container is not a DOM element" error. Could you explain what that means? I even tried replacing "document.body" with "document.getElementById('days-of-week') but it didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useRef` hook to access DOM elements.

Links that might help you:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.\